# Super Class Property Undefined Despite Super Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm attempting to program a text adventure game using ECMAScript 6, transpiling into ECMAScript 5 using Babel. I've run into a strange case that's not appearing elsewhere in my code.

I have a generic action class that parses commands, determines if a given input matches a command that triggers the action, and then calls function to actually execute the action.

```
/**
 * An action represents a mapping between a string and some kind of action in
 * the system.
 */
export class Action {
    /**
     * Construct a new action instance.
     */
    constuctor () {
        this.commands = [];
    }
    /**
     * Add a command as a trigger for this action.
     *
     * @param {String} command The command string to add as a trigger.
     *
     * @returns {Boolean} True if the command was added, false otherwise.
     */
    addCommand (command) {
        var paramRegex = /\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}/g;
        var i = 0;
        var regexResult;
        var commandRegex;
        var parameters;
        if (typeof command !== 'string' || command.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        parameters = {};
        // Make spaces generic
        commandRegex = command.replace(/\w+/g, '\\w+');
        regexResult = paramRegex.exec(commandRegex);
        while (regexResult) {
            parameters[i] = regexResult[1];
            commandRegex = commandRegex.replace(regexResult[0], '([^\\w]+)');
            i++;
            regexResult = paramRegex.exec(commandRegex);
        }
        this.commands.push({
            regex: new RegExp(commandRegex, 'gi'),
            parameters: parameters
        });
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the action has a trigger matching the given command string.
     *
     * @param {String} command The command to parse.
     *
     * @returns {Boolean} True if the command triggers the action, false
     * otherwise.
     */
    isTrigger (command) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.commands.length; i++) {
            if (this.commands[i].regex.test(command)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Trigger the action using the given command. This method checks if the
     * command is a trigger for the action, extracts any arguments from the
     * command string, and passes them to the {@link Action#execute} function
     * using {@link Function#apply}.
     *
     * @param {String} command The command to use to trigger the action.
     *
     * @returns {Boolean} True if the trigger was successful, false otherwise.
     */
    trigger (command) {
        var args;
        var result;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.commands.length; i++) {
            result = this.commands[i].regex.exec(command);
            if (result != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            return false;
        }
        args = [];
        for (i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
            args.push(result[i]);
        }
        this.execute.apply(this, args);
    }
    /**
     * Execute the action with the given arguments.
     *
     * @returns {Boolean} True if the execution was successful, false otherwise.
     *
     * @virtual
     */
    execute () {
        throw new Error('Not implemented');
    }
}
```

I have a sub-class which is supposed to implement a movement action and move the player from one location to another.

```
/**
 * An action that moves the player.
 *
 * @extends {Action}
 */
export class MoveAction extends Action {
    constructor () {
        super();

        this.addCommand('go to {place}');
        this.addCommand('move to {place}');
        this.addCommand('go {place}');
    }
    execute (place) {
        var loc = GameObject.getGameObject(place);
        if (!loc) {
            return false;
        }
        return player.setLocation(loc);
    }
}
```

I've run Babel on my code to produce compatible ECMAScript 5 code and attempted to run them manually via Node.JS to validate they work before I push them to my Git repository (I plan to write the test cases later).

I've run into an issue, though, where Node.JS complains that `this.commands` is undefined.

```
> var MoveAction = require('./compiled/actions/moveAction').MoveAction;
undefined
> var act = new MoveAction();
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at MoveAction.addCommand (compiled\action.js:64:26)
    at new MoveAction (compiled\actions\moveAction.js:41:39)
    at repl:1:11
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:248:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
```

I can't spot anything immediately wrong with what I've written and I've done something similar in other places in the current code without any issues. I'm going to keep poking at it to see if I can solve the issue myself, but if anyone has suggestions that could save me time, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, I misspelled `constructor` as `constuctor`.

Comment: I just started stripping apart the code in your class and noticed the typo as well - good catch!

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have read my code over a bit more closely before submitting a question. Lesson learned!